# React Router Props Parameter Not Appearing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to pass the prop values that are accessible to my component to my react router link, but I'm not seeing any value being populated in `params` key of the prop associated to the link. Is there something wrong I'm doing with the `<Link>` or `<Route>` section? I'm not seeing any errors that would indicate that my setup is wrong

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import AnnotationCard from './AnnotationCard';

//Annotation Card - Body
export default class AnnotationBody extends React.Component {
    render() {

        const type = this.props.type.toLowerCase();

        return (
            <Router>
            <div>
                <div className="row d-flex p-1">
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <h3> <Link to="annotations" params={{ annotationId: this.props.linkId }} className={"text-" + type}>{this.props.title}</Link></h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Route name="annotations" path='/app/annotation/:annotationId' component={AnnotationCard} />
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route is,

```
<Route name="annotations" path='/app/annotation/:annotationId' component={AnnotationCard} />
```

And your associated link for this route is,

```
<Link to="annotations" params={{ annotationId: this.props.linkId }} className={"text-" + type}>{this.props.title}</Link>
```

Here your `link` won't work as in route you are defining `path='/app/annotation/:annotationId'` and in link you are using only `to="annotations"`, so your link will end up with `base_url/annotations` in your browser and probably **`404 - page not found error`** as you don't have route for this.

As per [docs](https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html),

If you want to pass params to your link, you should do this,

```
<Link to={`/app/annotation/${this.props.linkId}`} className={"text-" + type}>{this.props.title}</Link>  //considering associate route for this link is with `path='/app/annotation/:annotationId'`
```

**Note:** You cannot pass `name` to `Route` as you are passing here,

```
<Route name="annotations" path='/app/annotation/:annotationId' component={AnnotationCard} />
```

As per [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/children-func),

`Route` has only following.

1. component
2. render: func
3. children: func
4. path: string | string[]
5. exact: bool
6. strict: bool
7. location: object
8. sensitive: bool

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Makes sense!